# unable to perform arithmetic operation on integer from char array

Tags: c, char

Here's a test program I made.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char arr[10];
    int res=0, p = 2;
    scanf(" %c",&arr[1]);
    
    if(arr[1]>=48 &&arr[1]<=57){
        res = arr[1] * p;
    }

    res = res+10;
    printf("%d",res);
}
```

For input `2`
the output is coming `110`,
which would happen when in `res = arr[1] * p`, instead of `2*2`, it will be performing `50*2`(ASCII value of 2).

How to correct this and why is it happening?

Comment: Subtract `48` from `arr[1]`. Or better subtract `'0'` (mind the quotes).

Comment: @EugeneSh. I incorporated your comments contribution into my answer. Let me know if you mind please. E.g. if you are making an answer.

Comment: @user3121023 Good point. It would allow for input like "255" to end up correctly. I recommend to turn that into an answer. But maybe ask whether OP actually want multi-digits to be treated as numbers. I seem not really clear to me.

Comment: @Yunnosch No problem at all

Comment: @user3121023 Really, you obviously can make an interesting answer. Go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the character `'2'` into the array, which you do with `"%c"` (or `" %c"`), then the value arriving there will be the ASCII code of "2", not the value 2.

The ASCII for "2" is much higher than 2.

As Eugene mentions in a comment, the method to adapt to the offset is to subtract the difference of ASCII and "digit-value", most efficiently and self-explainingly by subtracting the character (not the value) `'0'`.

Comment: Weird, this it the second answer today which I edited to incorporate a contribution - without a visible edit in the history.... It is called "grace period" isn't it?

Comment: I think if you make the edit fast enough, it does not show up

Comment: I was hoping that there is a "documented" difference between my stand-alone answer and the version with your contributionin the last paragraph. Ah well, as long as you don't mind....